# Rails 4: How to send decoded HTML in an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

Alrighty, I am creating the ability for a user to create their own html and then send it inside of a fancy HTML templated email.

I am using `Bootstrap WYSIWYG` for my cool rich text editor, encoding that...sending it to my controller.

My controller code looks like this:

```
@body = HTMLEntities.new.decode email.body
mail(to: email.to, subject: email.subject)
```

Nothing fancy...but when I send off my email, instead of being bold and beautiful text, the body of the email simply says <b>Text</b> rather than actually being **bold**

Is there something I need to do to get my mailer to process the body text as html?

Here is a snippet of my mailer html where I insert the body html text

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= @body %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use <%=raw @body %> or <%= @body.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 2):

similarly to Jiten K's answer

I like the short hand [<%==](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety)

`<%== @body %>`